# VBA - Creating an array that takes the max value of each row

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am trying to create a new function, that takes an `i` by `j` array, multiplies a fixed value to each column (`j` number of unique values), and returns an `i` by `1` array where each value will take the maximum value of each row after the multiplication.

The important thing here is to return an array, so that it can be combined with a sumproduct equation later.

I've attached the code I've tried below, but it does not work. Can somebody advise on how to do this? (Both building on the below or advice from scratch is fine)

I'm quite stuck and any advice would be appreciated!

```
Function NEWFUNCTION(A1 As Variant, M1, A2 As Variant, M2, A3 As Variant, M3)
    Dim i, n As Integer
    Dim calc1, calc2, calc3, Result As Variant

    For i = 0 To n
        calc1(i) = A1(i) * M1
        calc2(i) = A2(i) * M2
        calc3(i) = A3(i) * M3

        If calc1(i) >= calc2(i) And calc1(i) >= calc3(i) Then
           Result(i) = calc1(i)
        End If
        If calc2(i) >= calc1(i) And calc2(i) >= calc3(i) Then
           Result(i) = calc2(i)
           Else: Result(i) = calc3(i)
        End If
    Next
    getResult= Result
End Function
```

Comment: You've described what you are doing, but you have not asked a question.

Comment: Thanks for the callout - edited it. Basically, whats written up there is what I want to do, and the code is my take on it, but it does not work, so looking on advice for how to fix / or rewrite (if it's completely wrong)

Comment: Your function is not returning anything, `getResult= Result` should be `NEWFUNCTION= Result`. Also, n is not initialized. Maybe if you showed the input data and the desired output, someone would be able to help.